Procedural Block in Snowflake Scripting
I'm trying to load a table based on the next block:
BEGIN
    FOR counter in CURRENT_DATE to CURRENT_DATE+1000 DO
        INSERT INTO myTable AS SELECT counter;
    END FOR;
END;

Then I get the next error: Unexpected 'INTO'.
help

generate_series() equivalent in snowflake

You should never insert from loops, because it does N inserts, instead generate the data in one go and insert that:
select current_date() + value::number
from table(flatten(array_generate_range(0,1000)));


and thus:
create table myTable(date date);

INSERT INTO myTable 
    select current_date() + value::number
    from table(flatten(array_generate_range(0,1000)));


